# Rails index order and group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, grouping

I have a Products Controller where in the index action products are sorted by the "cost" column using this code:

> @products = Product.order(:cost)

I would like to keep this behavior but also group products that have the same EAN.

This is the actual behavior:

1. EAN: 777777, Cost: 5
2. EAN: 444444, Cost: 10
3. EAN: 222222, Cost: 15
4. EAN: 333333, Cost: 20
5. EAN: 444444, Cost: 25

This is the expected behavior:

1. EAN: 777777, Cost: 5
2. EAN: 444444, Cost: 10
3. EAN: 444444, Cost: 25
4. EAN: 222222, Cost: 15
5. EAN: 333333, Cost: 20

EDIT:

working solution thanks to @RocKhalil's answer:

```
products = Product.order(:cost)
products_hash = Hash.new
products.each_with_index do |product, i|
  unless product.ean.present?
    products_hash["index#{i}"] = product
  else
    products_hash[product.ean] = [] unless products_hash[product.ean]
    products_hash[product.ean] << product
  end
end

@products = products_hash.values.flatten
```

Comment: You should create a new question instead of total editing existing one requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't `group` them, you should simple order them in the correct way:

```
@products = Product.order(:ean, :cost)
```

---

### `EDIT`

```
products = Product.order(:cost)
products_hash = Hash.new

products.each do |product| 
  products_hash[product.ean] = [] unless products_hash[product.ean]
  products_hash[product.ean] << product
end

products_hash.map{|k,v| puts v }
```

Comment: Your suggestion would sort them by ean and then, within the same ean sort by cost. Will not work on my example. I need to sort by cost, and, when I list an item I want all the corrisponding eans right after it.

Comment: The answer is still basically correct, simply change the order: `Product.order(:cost, :ean)`

Comment: @Thilo nope; this won't help - it will order them by cost then by ean which isn't want he wants; he wants to order the by cost then group them by ean

Comment: @RocKhalil Not according to his example. That's ordered by `:cost` and then `:ean`, not grouped. It's a mismatch between the question text and the example, I guess.